# Adding columns to dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following:

`count = a[(a.type == 'exact') & (a.score == 1.0)].groupby('id').count()['type']
countbyid = pd.DataFrame(data = count)`

Which gives me the following:

`id     type
102116  578
1256    1211
126805  215
31560   12
329401  2310
49923   375
9691    2409`

When I try to [add column names](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to `countbyid = pd.DataFrame(data = count, columns = ['customer', 'department'])` NO data is returned, only the column names:

`customer   department`

Comment: I am not sure if you need dataframe constructor here, print count to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your given approach, you are inserting the dataframe which already has column names and when you assign the columns inside, no values against those columns are assigned, hence you receive a null dataframe.

So two approaches to tackle this problem -

First:

```
countbyid = pd.DataFrame(data = countbyid.values)
countbyid.columns = ['customer', 'department']
```

Second (as mentioned in comment by ScottBoston):

```
countbyid = pd.DataFrame(data= countbyid.values, columns = ['customer', 'department'])
```

Comment: @meW Nailed it, thanks for the help & the clarification as to why I was receiving the null dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I assume that `a` is a dataframe, you just need to reset index and rename columns. No need to call DataFrame constructor again.

```
a[(a.type == 'exact') & (a.score == 1.0)].groupby('id').type.count().reset_index()\
.rename({'id':'customer', 'type':'department'})
```